# App compact v7 error

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I am trying to modify my code to include the latest nav drawer as seen in Google play stand. For this the first step is to add the app compact v7 to my project. I first updated my SDK and then imported the library project. It threw some errors, I gooogled and set the version to 21 in Project properties. The errors were resolved.

Now when I try to add this to my project by importing the library I get all sort of resource not found errors. I am clueless as only after adding the app compact v7 to my project as a lib I get these errors what can be possibly wrong here?

I am following steps exactly as defined [here](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#libs-with-res)

Here is the screen shot without any errors on app compact v7: [image]

Comment: right click on your project or the app compact, and change the build target to 19 or the latest that you have.. clean, and shout expiliarmus!! and watch the magic erase all errors..lol

Comment: I donot have errors in the app compact - refer to the screenshot. Once I import and add it as a lib into my project I get all sort of R errors in my project and not in the app compact porject. However the errors on my console read missing resources

Comment: Sir, and i am deciphering this as, your compiling target or build target on your **project** (AuthSetupWizardworkflowlauncher) is api 15, right? if so, as you did for the appcompat do the same for your project, target a higher api.

Comment: I cannot target anything above 18 in my original project - It will mess up my alarm manager which is set up to setRepeating and works only with API 18.

Comment: well there is `setInexactRepeating` for api 19+.. so you can catch the build target programmatically and do the respective codes..any additional reasons why you don't want to target higher api??

Answer (score 2):

Right click on project --> Go to properties --> Go to Android --> Set Project Build Target as Android 5.0 or 5.0.1 --> Apply......Hope this will solve your problem

Comment: I donot have any error in the app compact project. Please read the question carefully. I am already done with what you explained.

Comment: set your project build target as 5.0.1 not the appcompat

Comment: or try setting both appcompat as well as your project build to 5.0.1... that might solve the problem coz even i faced the same problem and solved it that way...

Comment: Okay the number of errors is reduced now I have a different conflict now `oogle-play-services_lib/res/values/wallet_attrs.xml:7: error: Attribute "theme" has already been defined`

Comment: upgrade the googleplayservice library to the latest one by importing from the sdk...bro u r facing the exact problem that i faced few days ago :)